# Parameter(s) Unfilled error for pandas after updating pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have some pandas code I was working on in a dummy project I use for testing, and once I figured out this worked, started a new project and pasted the pandas code in. I'm now getting a Parameter(s) Unfilled error for the below script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\filepath...')


import_columns = ['List',
                  'Of',
                  'Import',
                  'Columns'
                  ]

file_a = pd.read_excel('1.1_A_Dummy Data.xlsx', usecols=lambda x: x in set(import_columns)) # ERROR
print(file_a)
```

Here is the warning flagged up in Pycharm:

[image]

I only get this error for new projects, it wasn't present in the original dummy project I wrote the script in. I've tried a clean install of pycharm and still get this error flagged, even though the code works fine. Is this something to do with the interpreter settings, or new versions of pandas etc? It works perfectly fine but I can't understand why it would be error flagging something that's never popped up whenever I've used read_excel.

EDIT: Here is the interpreter settings, i haven't inherited from global, nad just installed pandas and openpyxl:

[image]

Comment: do you mean runtime is ok, just design time warinings?

Comment: Yes, it functions exactly as intended but is flagging the Parameter(s) Unfilled for all instances where read_excel is used.

Comment: double check `settings-project settings`, the interpreter is intended one?

Comment: I've added my interpreter settings as a screenshot above. Nothing out the ordinary i can spot.

Comment: what pycharm version are you using? i tried myself but didn't see so long method help text.

Comment: 2021.3.2, most recent version.

Answer (score 16):

Okay so I've found something rather odd. `sheet_name` now just seems to be marked as a mandatory field, rather than an optional, but still runs correctly without it. Adding `sheet_name=0` stops the error flags from appearing:

```
file_a = pd.read_excel('1.1_A_Dummy Data.xlsx', sheet_name=0, usecols=lambda x: x in set(import_columns))
```

I'm not sure if I can classify this as a "solution", but I'm posting this as an answer. I've searched the pandas changelog for any indication this is a version issue, but have come across nothing. If anyone else has a more thorough explanation feel free to elaborate.

Comment: *sheet_name now just seems to be marked as a mandatory field* --- if you paste the corresponding proof, then the answer should be valid.

Comment: Very weird because sheet_name is supposed to be an optional argument if you look at the source code (https://i.imgur.com/jhe2Q9w.png).